# Timer in Javafx Creating FX Thread null pointers and out of bounds exceptions

Tags: timer, javafx

I was trying to make a simple timer in Javafx with a GUI and Timer class.  When the start button is pressed, it is supposed to count down from the inputed time and stop when it reaches 0.

I have the remaining time in milliseconds updating in a TextField on the GUI but it only runs for a random number of milliseconds usually between 100-200 and then it freezes up and throws a VERY large number of exceptions.

I tried to pinpoint where the error was coming from, and found there was also a concurrent modification exception as well.

Here is my Timer class:

```
import java.sql.Time;

/**
 * Created by Josh on 19/8/2015.
 */
public class Timer {

    private long endTimeMillis;

    public Timer(long hours, long minutes, long seconds){

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        endTimeMillis = ((seconds*1000 + minutes*1000*60 + hours*1000*60*60) + currentTime);

    }

    public boolean isFinished(){

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if(endTimeMillis - currentTime <= 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public long getRemainingTimeMillis(){

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        return endTimeMillis - currentTime;

    }

}
```

and this is the GUI

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

/**
 * Created by Josh on 19/8/2015.
 */
public class GUI extends Application {

    private BorderPane root;

    Label hoursLabel, minutesLabel, secondsLabel;
    TextField hoursTF, minutesTF, secondsTF;

    Button startButton;

    Label remainingTimeLabel;
    TextField remainingTimeTF;

    long remainingTime;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        root = new BorderPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1300, 125));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Timer");
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
                event.consume();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        FlowPane center = new FlowPane();
        hoursLabel = new Label("     Hours: ");
        hoursTF = new TextField();
        minutesLabel = new Label("     Minutes: ");
        minutesTF = new TextField();
        secondsLabel = new Label("     Seconds: ");
        secondsTF = new TextField();
        center.getChildren().addAll(hoursLabel, hoursTF, minutesLabel, minutesTF, secondsLabel, secondsTF);
        root.setCenter(center);

        FlowPane bottom = new FlowPane();
        bottom.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        startButton = new Button("Start");
        startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                start();
            }
        });
        remainingTimeLabel = new Label("     Time Remaining: ");
        remainingTimeTF = new TextField();
        bottom.getChildren().addAll(startButton, remainingTimeLabel, remainingTimeTF);
        root.setBottom(bottom);


    }



    public void start(){

        Task timer = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                long hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0;

                try{
                    if(hoursTF.getText() == null || hoursTF.getText().equals("")){
                        hours = 0;
                    }else{
                        hours = Long.parseLong(hoursTF.getText());
                    }
                    if(minutesTF.getText() == null || minutesTF.getText().equals("")){
                        minutes = 0;
                    }else{
                        minutes = Long.parseLong(minutesTF.getText());
                    }
                    if(secondsTF.getText() == null || secondsTF.getText().equals("")){
                        seconds = 0;
                    }else{
                        seconds = Long.parseLong(secondsTF.getText());
                    }
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("Error");

                }

                Timer timer = new Timer(hours, minutes, seconds);

                while(!timer.isFinished()){
                    remainingTimeTF.setText(Long.toString(timer.getRemainingTimeMillis()));
                }


                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(timer).start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

New stack trace:

```
    x.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
    at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
    at GUI$3.call(GUI.java:109)
    at GUI$3.call(GUI.java:80)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:438)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:364)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:113)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.updateChildren(LabeledSkinBase.java:575)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabeledSkinBase.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabeledSkinBase.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.LabelSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(LabelSkin.java:49)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$$Lambda$102/1442917786.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(StringPropertyBase.java:103)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.markInvalid(StringPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringPropertyBase.set(StringPropertyBase.java:49)
    at javafx.beans.property.StringProperty.setValue(StringProperty.java:65)
    at javafx.scene.control.Labeled.setText(Labeled.java:145)
    at GUI$3.call(GUI.java:109)
    at GUI$3.call(GUI.java:80)
    at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? I would assume this would give an `IllegalStateException` due to you modifying the scene graph from a background thread, but maybe there are other errors you hit first.

Comment: The stack trace is extremely long but i will add a small portion of it

Comment: Be sure to include the first portion that references code you wrote (and identify the line it points to from your code)

Comment: OK one sec the trace was too long and the top wasn't actually the top

Comment: Is this Java 7 / JavaFX 2.2?

Comment: its javafx 8 version 8u51

Comment: The stack trace doesn't point to anywhere in my code it seems?

Comment: Yeah, weird. Apparently `TextField`s don't check you're obeying the threading rules. Change the `remainingTimeTF` to a label and you get the more useful exception.

Comment: Yeah that worked, errors at remainingTimeTF.setText(Long.toString(timer.getRemainingTimeMillis())); and  Task timer = new Task<Void>() {  I updated the new stack trace by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are violating the rule about not accessing the state of a node in a live scene graph on a background thread. Most JavaFX controls will actually check for this and throw an `IllegalStateException` when you do this: apparently `TextInputControl.setText(...)` doesn't (presumably for reasons of performance).

The simplest fix is to update the message property of the task:

```
            while(!timer.isFinished()){
              updateMessage(Long.toString(timer.getRemainingTimeMillis()));
              // remainingTimeTF.setText(Long.toString(timer.getRemainingTimeMillis()));
            }
```

(this causes an update to the message property to occur on the FX Application Thread), and then bind the text field's text property to it:

```
    remainingTimeTF.textProperty().bind(timer.messageProperty());
    new Thread(timer).start();
```

However, there are a lot of things about your code that violate good practice. Fo example, you should really compute the total time outside of the task (i.e. on the FX Application Thread) and store it in a `final` variable; and the busy while loop is pretty horrible (though `updateMessage(...)` will fix most of the issues associated with that for you).

I recommend you read up on multithreading in JavaFX. Start with the [`Task` API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html). Maybe this question will help: [Using threads to make database requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249493/using-threads-to-make-database-requests)

Comment: Yes you are right i will try this and this is very good idea!

Comment: Works perfectly THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you really need to update that TextField in the way you are doing it I would recommend adding a `Thread.sleep(100);` (10 updates per second) in your while, or even `Thread.sleep(1000);` (1 update per second) since it's really CPU intensive to update that text field on every CPU cycle and usually you don't need to..

Secondly (and probably the reason of your exceptions) the call `remainingTimeTF.setText();` MUST happen **IN the FX Thread**, try this code instead:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        remainingTimeTF.setText(Long.toString(timer.getRemainingTimeMillis()));
    }
});
```

Right now you are setting the text outside the FX Thead which might lead to several exceptions since update requests are happening in a worker thread and the actual UI modifications are happening in the FX thread. You need to make sure that every time you need to modify the UI it happens in the correct thread, in this case the FX Thread with the `Platform.runLater()` call.

Also since you are already using the Task class why not bind the text property and use the updateMessage() or updateTitle() methods instead?
Take a look at [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm), it has good examples for the correct usage of Task and updating the UI from worker threads.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, if you use `Platform.runLater(...)` here you ***must*** include a `Thread.sleep(...)`. Else the poor FX Application thread will still be trying to perform updates for a very, very long time. But, it's much better to use the built-in facilities from `Task`, which deal with a lot of these issues for you.

Comment: YES! I have tried this without the Thread.sleep() and I got no errors but my program just froze haha!  Now it all makes sense

Comment: Glad this helped! Keep up learning and as James suggested it's best to stick with the API provides you instead of reinventing the wheel :)